# Which UWP version should I choose for XBox One?

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to build a UWP app that works on both desktop and xbox one in Visual Studio 2019. At project creation it wants to know the targetted and minimum versions, with a link to an article ['Choose a UWP Version'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/updates-and-versions/choose-a-uwp-version). This article has no mention of Xbox at all.

Target version has only one option, build 1903.

Minimum has a selection of old Windows 10 versions, basically all the releases since 10.0, with a default of 1809.

- Do I need to install something extra into Visual Studio, or will the
  default work ok?
- If I get it wrong, is changing this likely to work
  or foul up the project?
- Or do I need to set a specific minimum for
  UWP on Xbox One?

Comment: Seems like a [getting started tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/getting-started) is what you should follow.

Comment: To be fair, that page doesn't talk about Desktop either. You pick the UWP version that you want to target. Here's [a list of UWP versions available on Xbox](https://beta.support.xbox.com/help/hardware-network/settings-updates/whats-new-xbox-one-system-updates). Latest is 18363 as of this writing. If you want to run on older Xbox systems, you can choose a lower version.

Comment: Thanks! This helps greatly - Windows 10 1903 is 18363, so I can just use the defaults.

Comment: Yes that page doesn't say desktop, but it does say Windows 10. I'm assuming that means desktop, and that xbox is not Windows 10. Maybe it is now, maybe there's no difference from a dev POV.